# Select current Array item after using `$filter` to see if it is even there

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a stored procedure that returns a comma separated list of numbers. I take that and `split` it into an `array`

Using `angular.forEach()` I then need to search an array(scope.dataForStoreHierachy) for and id with the matching number.

```
var found = $filter('filter')(scope.dataForStoreHierachy, { id: parseInt(current) }, true);
```

That works fine, but is there a way to isolate that particular item within the array to look up other properties of the element?

Answer (score 0):

To get the singular element I used the code below

```
$filter('filter')(scope.dataForStoreHierachy, function (d) { return d.id === parseInt(current); })[0]
```